# How do I get any given element of a map in Go?

Tags: dictionary, go

Suppose I have a `map[string]int`, and I want the key with the shortest length (in bytes). If I don't know any particular element that the map contains, how do I get a sample of it so I can do

```
var shortest string
for key, _ := range myMap {
    if len(key) < len(shortest) {
        shortest = key
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question; why wouldn't the code sample you provided work?

Comment: @william.taylor.09 Meant it to be the shortest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and break out of it immediately to sample just one element.

```
var shortest string
for key, _ := range myMap {
    shortest = key
    break
}
for key, _ := range myMap {
    if len(key) < len(shortest) {
        shortest = key
    }
}
```

Ugly, but it works.

Comment: Sorry, EMBLEM. I had downvoted since OP had asked for the shorted, and you provided the longest. OP then commented he wanted the shorted, and I provided an answer for the shortest. In the meantime, you had edited your answer to reflect the shorted. However, it won't allow me to change my vote unless you re-edit the question. I'd gladly upvote you if you provide a quick edit to the answer, so S.O. will stop complaining.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 I am the OP. I had answered my own question.

Comment: @EMBLEM, select it as the answer. And sometimes ugly and working is just what you need

Comment: @matt.s Yes. I know. You do know I can't accept my own answer for 2 days?

Comment: @EMBLEM, oops, I forgot

Comment: your solution works, but I do think defining a var to record the shortest length will solve all problems, like depicted in @desaiparth's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should first define two variables `shortestLength` and `shortest`, they will record shortest length you found until now, and corresponding key, respectively. And then start iterating over the map.

Here, the trick is to initialise `shortestLength` variable with a value, which will be over-written in the first pass. The benefit is that, you don't have to write any extra code and allocate extra memory to sort the keys, and find the shortest one.

Complete code is as following:

```
if len(myMap) == 0 {
   // Empty map
}

// Will be over-written in first iteration
shortestLength := maths.MaxInt32
shortest := ""

for key, _ := range myMap {
  keyLength := len(key)
  if keyLength <= shortestLength {
    shortest = key
    shortestLength = keyLength
  }
}
```

The variable `shortestLength` will be over-written with the length of first element in the first iteration of our for loop. And at the end of the loop will contain the length of shortest key. And `shortest` will contain the key itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the map, adding the elements to a slice. Then sort the slice:

```
var keys []string
for k := range myMap {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
sort.Strings(keys) // keys[0] is the shorted
```

GoPlay: http://play.golang.org/p/DULIiQAkfg